# Python subprocess list files without "\n"

Tags: python, subprocess, strip

I'm using `subprocess` on python to list all the files/folders in one folder:

```
def subprocess_list(command):
  p = subprocess.Popen(command,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
  proc_stdout = p.communicate()[0].strip()
  lista.append(proc_stdout.decode('utf-8'))
  retcode = p.wait()
subprocess_list('ls | grep aa')
```

When I print "lista" I get all the paths in a single-element list:

```
lista=[aaa\naab\naac\n]
```

So in order to separate them and get each file I first export them to a .txt, call it back and delete `\n`

```
with open('%s/files.txt'%Path_Desktop,'w') as file:
    for item in lista:
        file.write(item)

with open('%s/files.txt'%Path_Desktop) as file:
    content = file.readlines()
content = [x.strip() for x in content]
```

Print "content":

```
content=['aaa','aab','aac']
```

Is there a way to do it directly without the export part? Thanks in advance!

Comment: How about `output.split('\n')` (`list` is not a good variable name). Or `os.listdir()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the subprocess for this, don't know if correct or the same but so far it's working well.

```
lista = (os.popen('ls | grep aa').read()).split('\n')
```

Comment: why do you want to use a subprocess for a task, python can do natively and even better?

Comment: Well, I started to python a few weeks ago, I started looking for info on the web and subprocess was what I found first. I tried os once but I had the problem with the split plart so I chose subprocess, list and export/import to txt

Answer (score 2):

first, you souldn't use subprocess to call ls. For your purpose the glob or os module is the better choice.

Why do you get "\n" strings? Well, you just call a subprocess which will return it's output as string.

With your suprocess-ls solution, you could now go on and split your string by "\n", to get a real python list.

```
list = list.split("\n")
```

Much better would be using glob instead. https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html

```
import glob
list = glob.glob("*aa*")
```

You would get exactly what you want, but it's the much faster, safer, pythonic and better solution.